# AWS: Getting bulk hits from different IPs on a single page

Tags: amazon-web-services

I know this might be really basic. My website is down as I am getting too many requests on few of my pages from foreign IPs. I tried blocking those but I started getting request from different set of IPs.

The CPU utilization of all servers is 99%. Looks like DDOS attack but how can I fix it for now?

[image]

Comment: what are you using a service deployed on EC2? Are you using ELB or Route 53? The reason I ask is Amazon says they enable AWS Sheild if you use Route 53 and/or ELB that might help with the DoS or DDoS requets

Comment: We use HAproxy for load-balancing and Route53 as DNS

Comment: Take a look at AWS Shield to see if that can help you.

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Comment: Note that outside of India, people will not know what a "lakh" is, and the term is best avoided.